# Entity Framework Timeout Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have this method

```
public static List<SummaryItinerary> ReturnBookingsByUserGuid(Guid userGuid)
         {
             var entities = new gHOPEntities();
             var results = from itinerary in entities.Itinerary
                          where itinerary.UserGuid == userGuid
                          where itinerary.Booking
                          select new SummaryItinerary()
                                     {
                                         TourTitle = itinerary.Tours.Title,
                                         TourId = itinerary.Tours.TourId,
                                         TourSEOName =
itinerary.Tours.SEOName,
                                         DepartureDate =
itinerary.DepartureDate,
                                         Passengers = itinerary.Passengers,
                                         Nights = itinerary.Nights,
                                         GrandTotal = itinerary.GrandTotal,
                                         AmountPaid = itinerary.AmountPaid,
                                         CreationDate =
itinerary.CreationDate
                                     };
             var summaryItineraryList = new List<SummaryItinerary>();

             foreach(var summaryItinerary in results)
             {
                 summaryItineraryList.Add(summaryItinerary);
             }

             return summaryItineraryList.OrderByDescending(i =>
i.CreationDate).ToList();
         }
```

This method fails when I call it.  A timeout error is returned.  However, when I put a breakpoint at the for loop, it passes.  Why is this happening?

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: note: you can use `summaryItineraryList.AddRange(result)` instead foreach loop

Comment: @Sachin when you're in debug you can get the result of the method call ReturnBookingsByUserGuid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is beacuse in loop:

```
foreach(var summaryItinerary in results)
```

on every element it looks into database. This is enumerable, so access is through each element, and every element iteration checks database. To avoid that do following:

```
var tmp = results.ToList();
foreach(var summaryItinerary in tmp)
```